# Sending Mail via commons-email-1.3.2

Tags: java, arraylist, sendmail

I have problem with `ArrayList` mailing again. Program building and working succesfully about 1 month. But today i detect some important mails not coming from my program. And I begin debugging my code. Let me share my findings.

I have a `Arraylist` populated from some DB queries;

```
ArrayList<String> importantlist = new ArrayList<String>();
```

When populating complete I send this `Arraylist` to Mail sender method;

```
if (importantlist.size() > 0) {
    sendMail(importantlist);
}
```

sendMail method;

```
public void sendMail(ArrayList cominglist) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for(Object coming: cominglist)
        b.append(coming).append("\n");     
    String cominglistString = b.toString(); 
    Email email = new SimpleEmail();
    email.setHostName("hostname here");
    email.setSmtpPort(587);
    email.setAuthentication("mail sender user here","userpasswordhere");
    email.setSSLOnConnect(false);
    email.setFrom("mail sender address here");
    email.setSubject("Example important list");
    email.setMsg("Example important List body;\n"+cominglistString);
    email.addTo("receiver user here");
    email.addTo("receiver user here");
    email.send();
    System.out.println("success");
}
```

When I debug this method I see message is `null` when cursor come to `email.send();` But this program work succesfully and send lists to users about 1 month.

If I try another sendMail method just like below, mails succesfully coming to my mailbox;

```
public void sendMail2() throws Exception {
    Email email = new SimpleEmail();
    email.setHostName("hostname here");
    email.setSmtpPort(587);
    email.setAuthentication("mail sender user here","userpasswordhere");
    email.setSSLOnConnect(false);
    email.setFrom("mail sender address here");
    email.setSubject("Example simple mail");
    email.setMsg("Example simple mail body;\n");
    email.addTo("receiver user here");
    email.addTo("receiver user here");
    email.send();
    System.out.println("success");
}
```

**---Edit---**

```
email.setMsg("Example important List body;\n"+cominglistString); line edited.
```

And yes, my list is bigger than 0 I am sure.

Any idea?

**---Edit 2---**

Really i am shocked now!! I continue debugging and mail come to my mailbox this time when i debugging. Because i see `cominglistString` and `email` message box populated this time. Mails dont came sometimes. I am stuck :(

Comment: What is the value of `cominglistString`? Is it as you expected ie. a valid string?

Comment: 1 example line is: [12134 OUT MEMBER] [Für_Sec: 1613] [Füs_Sec: 5673] [%245  Command Für]

Comment: Are you using thread to send mail? It may happen while threading if you SimpleMail class is not threadsafe.

Comment: @ManishVerma Above if condition for mail sending stored in SwingWorker's doInBackground method. And sendMail method defined under main SwinWorker Class. Does this cause problem?

Comment: Hey I do not know much about SwinWorker Class. Anyways You can google it for its threadsafe problems and complexity in you java version.
I got this type of problem with SimpleDateFormat Class. After much debugging I found that the class is not threadsafe. Then I make it threadsafe and then everything work fine.

Comment: How can I identify exactly what is the problem? I debug the code now and everythings normal, mails sending, readable from mailbox etc..

Comment: If it works when you debug it but not work running @Manish Verma is probably right about threads.  To know what is going on on runtime use some sort of logging into a file or screen before and after each important task so you might know which part is not executed or creating a problem.

Comment: @Rusty30 I detect strange thing. I copy the program to my laptop and start it. If program running on my laptop succesfully working. Working on other machine but mails dont came. I update problematic machine's Java but not solve the problem. Both machines Win7 64 Bit and program start succesfully but one of can't send mails. What you think ?

Comment: is the problematic computer sending some email but not all of them?  Maybe some connectivity issues that prevent the mail from departing?  I still think the best to debug this (although tedious) is to make the program do outputs to screen or file to verify which portion of the code is not being reached.

Comment: One Note: Some other .NET programs running on problematic machine and these are connect same Mail Server with same Mail User and send some reports. These are succesfully coming. Only my program stop sending mails today. Really strange. I dont know how can i logging to file in Java. Could you please share some useful links for example ?

Comment: Hey if this is a thread issue then only thing will matter is the core of the machine.(Parallel processing power of the machine). Why not you log every suspected variable in some file and try to reproduce the issue in original machine.If the process is running in parallel then each thread will execute the line same time and it will be printed on the file. Just see when the suspected variable has got value which is unexpected. If it happens then...Thread Issue.

Comment: (Use any logging library in JAVA System.out.println(Variable.value) will print in the log file of the server where you have hosted. e.g.  catalina.out in case of tomcat.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved. It was a local Firewall problem. Firewall block communication between Application Machine and Mail Server.

Firewall restarted and problem is gone.

Thanks for all answers.